# ActionRedirect migration to Struts 2

Tags: java, struts2, migration, struts, actionresult

I'm currently migrating a wepapp from Struts to Struts 2 and I'm experiencing some difficulties.

I have some `ActionRedirect` with no extra parameters given to it and I don't know how to migrate it, maybe just return a string is efficient?

For example I have this :

```
return new ActionRedirect(mapping.getFindforward("failed");
```

Is it efficient to do that instead ?

```
return "failed";
```

And when I have parameters how can i migrate it ? I'm working on that part since 2 days.

Comment: we have constants in Action class in struts2.like success,error...etc.You can use like Action.ERROR...etc

Comment: I know that but it's the ActionRedirect which give problems to me

Comment: can u explain clearly

Comment: I don't know with what replace the ActionRedirect return :/

Comment: @BlackMario The name of the result; a string.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In Struts2 redirects are made if you create the result of type `"redirect"` if you want to redirect to a specific URL, 
or `"redirectAction"` if you want to redirect to the known action in the configuration.

These results you may configure on action or globally like forwards in the Struts1.

The difference is that you don't need to find it in the `mapping` it will be done by the framework.

If you return `"failed"` the framework will look up the configuration for the result named `"failed"` and if it fails finding such result it will throw an exception.

Answer (score 0):

In struts.xml class you can specify

```
<result type="redirect"      
name="failed">redirect action name</result>
```

In the action class you can use

return "falure"

or any of the constants existed in Action class

Comment: Ok i also saw this but in struts 1 all this process is made in the action java class so i hoped that this could be possible in struts 2...

Comment: @PSR The result type should be "redirectAction" if you want to specify only the redirect action name. With a "redirect" you need to specify the complete URL.