# Struts action result redirecting to wrong URL

Tags: struts2, struts

Our application is hosted under a folder in a domain. When struts action result returns a JSP page, it is removing the that folder. So the JSP page is not loading

Our App is hosted in `domain.com/vendor`

Here vendor is a folder under the domain

When action result return a JSP page, URL is

`domain.com/project1/private/attendance.jsp`

Here "vendor" folder is missing

```xml
    <package name="private" namespace="/private" extends="struts-default">
        <action name="attendanceRegister" class="com.emob.web.PunchAction"
            method="listAttendance">
                <result name="success">/private/attendance.jsp</result>
        </action>
    </package>
```

Please let me know the configuration so that the folder is returned in result URL

Comment: Unrelated, but in general, you'll always want to keep your JSP pages under `WEB-INF` to prevent direct access. The result processing takes the string you provide without modification, so I suspect there's something else at play, like your deployment or server setup. The JSP URL you're providing is what's being used, which is correct.

Comment: Make sure you use default result type a dispatcher which is used by default. https://stackoverflow.com/a/15115126/573032